# Is there any convention to sustainably place bits of different software in one file

Tags: linux, shell, configuration

There are some files like .bashrc or linux config files (cannot remind them right now), which contain lines of information inserted by different software/apps/libraries, e.g. when they were installed.

Is there any way to differentiate information in such files, i.e. to know which lines belong to which software? Maybe there is some convention for that? If yes, where can I learn about it. If no, how do software clean up their configuration and other property in OS files on uninstall?

**A note about tags:**
*I mentioned low-level languages as well as linux and shell because I think only guys from those techs may know the answer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there any way to differentiate information in such files, i.e. to know which lines belong to which software" - No.

You are dealing with plain text files and there is *no* way to tell who put what into those files. It may have been a program you installed/ran or it may have simply been a user editing the file in a text editor - you *don't* know.

You also have *no way* of knowing whether the contents of the file is well formed or not until you parse it.
If the file does not parse (is messed up) you have two options: 1) read what you can and discard everything else. 2) give up and tell the user the file is garbage

In any case, you cannot *trust* the information in the file. *Anyone* could have put it there.

Comment: Thank, you for the answer, Jesper. As a c++ developer, do you frequently encounter a need to edit/parse files which are edited/parsed by another software as well? Is it a big pain or not?

Comment: @Nurbol Alpysbayev I rarely/never encounter a need to do that in ~25years of writing C++. In *my* experience it is simply not a problem I have.

Comment: Wow. I wonder why do even I encounter this (though also rearely enough) in 10 years exp. and JS stack...